# Initialize firebase.initializeApp0 with provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Is there any way to initialize my fluttere fireabase app with provider?
I know the traditional way to initialize the firebase app with a FutureBuilder() widget,
but i would like to know if there is the possibility to initialize my flutterfire app.

Comment: You can launch your firebase app wherever you like, I do the initialization in the main file myself first of all.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. But that's a bit broad for Stack Overflow, so I recommend checking out some of these search results about [flutter firebase with provider](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+firebase+with+provider), such as https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-flutter-firebase/, https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-provider-architecture-with-firebase-full-guide-by-building-a-working-crud-app-4824cec04e59, and https://medium.flutterdevs.com/firebase-authentication-using-provider-in-flutter-522841a2ee4d.